# Does SAP Hana have a concept equivalent to Postgres' Row Level Security (RLS)

Tags: hana

Does SAP Hana have a concept equivalent to [Postgres' Row Level Security (RLS)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-rowsecurity.html)?

This is how you would do it in Postgres

```sql
CREATE TABLE accounts (manager text, company text, contact_email text);

ALTER TABLE accounts ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY account_managers ON accounts TO managers
    USING (manager = current_user);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, HANA has [analytic privileges](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b3ee5778bc2e4a089d3299b82ec762a7/2.0.03/en-US/db08ea0cbb571014a386f851122958b2.html), than transparently filter data on each query. User cannot overcome such filters, they work before SQL filters.
As guide says, you can assign SQL privilege to SQL view, not a table, so your table should be wrapped for this to work. Also SQL privilege has no "view all" option, you should explicitly grant all the privileges to user. XML analytic privilege is older and less flexible, also it has "view all" role (_SYS_BI_CP_ALL analytic privilege).

Comment: That's correct - HANA implements access security as a part of view development. The current documentation https://help.sap.com/viewer/b3ee5778bc2e4a089d3299b82ec762a7/2.0.05/en-US/db08ea0cbb571014a386f851122958b2.html references Row-Level Security explictily. Worthwhile to mention is that this view based apporach also allows for masking and de-identification of columns based on users' permissions.

Comment: Postgres' RLS will also block users from writing to the table if the operation violates the RLS policies. Is it possible to do it with Hana as well? 
We use Postgres' RLS to do the tenant data segregation as shown in the blog post below. I'm trying to find out if we can do something similar with Hana so that the tenant segregation is transparent for the developers, i.e. they don't have to filter by tenantId in every query. 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/multi-tenant-data-isolation-with-postgresql-row-level-security/

Comment: @FelipeTaiarol SAP way to do multitenancy in tables is `mandt`/`client` field. It is implemented in ERP side transparently adding `mandt` filter to all SQL statements from ABAP side (this is a system field at application level available in all programs, and every user logs into single mandant/client). This concept is partially translated into DBMS (some things works in DB engine under the hood), e.g. this field can filter data on Calculation View consumption (only `SELECT`), but I didn't tested it for insert on tables. Think there's no such out-of-the-box feature.